# How is a headset that does not have a band around the head called?

Tags: headphones, headset, terminology

How do I search in the leading auction site for the PC headset (earpiece + microphone) that does not have a band to go around or over your head - instead it is entirely like a cable, with the microphone attached in one of the wires leading from the ear piece? How is it called?

I'm not talking about Bluetooth wireless headsets.

I have one from Plantronics I got years ago, which they stopped making and I want another one, but don't know how to search. Simply searching for HeadSet or similar terms, brings mostly the newer ones which I don't want.

Edit: The microphone is 'inline' and the headset is stereo.

Comment: H81N? http://www.plantronics.com/north_america/en_US/productSearch/prod440084

Comment: In my headset, the microphone doesn't hang out like that; in fact, you won't even know the thing has a microphone unless you look closer.

Comment: It is stereo, not single ear. I will try to post a picture some where else when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for an "earbud" style headset or hands-free device.

I don't know of any other term that distinguishes headphones-without-headband from headphones-with-headband.

Comment: They could be meaning something like these (Long link ahead)

http://www.amazon.com/Sony-MDR-Q22LP-Headphones-Interchangeable-Headphone/dp/B00008VIX2/ref=sr_1_1/179-8882693-9892223?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1270588916&sr=8-1

Those are referred to as clip-on headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard them referred to as [single ear headsets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VEHT86). The picture doesn't seem right for what you're asking, though.